# Page title of Bibliography even on following page

Tags: biblatex

I have a bibliography followed by some other sections yet the bibliography title appears on subsequent pages. How to close the bibliography section and page styling?

```
\printbibliography[heading=bibintoc]
\newpage
\include{cv}
```

[image]

Preamble (not a mwe):

```
\RequirePackage[patch]{kvoptions} 
\documentclass[en-US,de-DE]{DissOnlineLatex}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{xfrac}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{cfr-lm} %font mit kursiven caps
\usepackage{sectsty}
\allsectionsfont{\sffamily}

\DeclareUnicodeCharacter{FEFF}{} %to get rid of the BOM character warning when using pasted text from LibreOffice
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
    \babeltags{de = ngerman}
    \babeltags{en = english}
\RequirePackage[ngerman=ngerman-x-latest]{hyphsubst}
\usepackage{datetime2}

\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage{lipsum, bibentry}

\usepackage{tabu} %tabellen
\usepackage{multirow}

\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,svgnames,table]{xcolor} %http://www.december.com/html/spec/colorsvg.html

\usepackage{qrcode}
\qrset{link, height=1.3cm}

% Zeitstrahl:
\input{zeitstrahl}

\usepackage{enotez}

%\usepackage{nameref}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}

\usepackage[autostyle,german=quotes,strict=true]{csquotes}

% Bibliographie:
\inputencoding{utf8}
\usepackage[
  style=authoryear-ibid,
  maxnames=2,
  backend=biber,
  safeinputenc,
  isbn=false,
  doi=false,
  maxcitenames=2,
  urldate=iso8601,
  date=iso8601
]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{PhD.bib}
\addbibresource{MyPublications.bib}
\DeclareLabeldate{
    \field{date}
    \field{eventdate} 
    \field{origdate}
    \literal{nodate}
}
\input{linkcitations}

%-zusaetzliche Kommandos
\input{command}

% Eigene Trennungsregeln* 
\include{hyphenations} 

% Glossar:
\usepackage[toc,section=chapter,style=long,smallcaps,acronym,xindy={glsnumbers=false},order=letter,nopostdot]{glossaries}
\usepackage{glossaries-extra}
\makeglossaries
\usepackage[xindy]{imakeidx}
\makeindex
\loadglsentries{glossary}
```

Comment: As always on this site, please post a full minimal example instead of sniplet(s). This makes it a lot easier for others to help

Comment: Might be easier to remove the LITERATUR in a pdf editor then to create a mwe...

Comment: Definitely not! But it all depends on the document class and preamble you are using, none of which you share with us.

Comment: And where is `DissOnlineLatex` available? It is not a standard class

Comment: On the website of the German National Library: http://www.dnb.de/DE/Wir/Projekte/Archiv/dissonlineTutor.html

Comment: Also note that others cannot run this "MWE" as it attempts to include stuff we do not have access to. Please make a standalone doc full doc. I looked at the class, it seems to be replacable by the the report class. Also remove everything not needed to give this issue. Basically we need a single doc that we can run without having to add anything.

Comment: Are you sure you are actually compiling something without errors? If I take the files from the URL you provided, and add you preamble, I get option class errors on inputenc

Comment: I get no headers at all with the data you have provided so far.

Comment: Yes, sorry, the files need to be converted to UTF8 for whatever reason with `iconv -f iso-8859-1 -t utf-8 original.tex converted.tex`. with `file --mime-encoding *.tex` you can see the various encodings they are in.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/72926/discussion-between-max-n-and-daleif).

Comment: Your template is *really* old and unsupported: "Leider kann 5 Jahre nach Abschluss des Projektes kein Support für diese mehr angeboten werden" (and we are now at ten years after project termination). I can't test your example because it is not completely minimal, but does `\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{\chapter*{#1}\addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}}` help?

Comment: @moewe was already typing that out. Though, since my German is not what it used to be, I never caught the age and support thing.

Comment: moewe & daleif  please accept my apologies for the missing mwe and my gratitude for taking the time to solve this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After chatting with the OP, it turns out the `biblatex` version being used is from 2016, where the `heading=` would always add to the headers. This combined with the use of `\pagestyle{myheadings}` caused `\bibname` to be added to the headers giving the bibliography and all subsequent pages `\bibname` in the header.

I did have a TeXLive version on disk with the same `biblatex` version, and the following will solve the problem (the best solution, of course, is to upgrade, but again of course, never just before handing in an important assignment)

```
\defbibheading{bibintoc}[\bibname]{%
  \chapter*{#1}%
  \addcontentsline{toc}{chapter}{#1}%
%  \markboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}
}
```

This was just copied from `biblatex_.def` (from the twosided branch, thus the `\chapter*`), and the `\markboth` was outcommented)

Comment: +1 Great minds think [alike](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/414503/page-title-of-bibliography-even-on-following-page#comment1035520_414503).

Comment: @moewe Since I normally don't use `biblatex`, I had to recreate the situation first. Did not occur to me to start by looking at the `\defbibheading` stuff.

Comment: Well it's always easier to guess the solution if you were the one who changed the code between the version the OP uses and `biblatex` 3.10 ;-) (and caused a few complaints about the new behaviour here and there, though in this case I seem to have gotten it right).

Comment: @moewe hehe, that is also why I can often solve `memoir` questions quite fast.

Comment: @moewe bug report: the current biblatex manual only states 3.9!

Comment: Thanks. [Already noted.](https://github.com/plk/biblatex/issues/680) We're hoping to release 3.11 soon, so hoped we didn't have to bother with that.

Comment: @moewe I probably have to start using it at one point, but I rarely write anything from scratch any more. I mostly editong stuff others have written and thus use what ever they used.